# How to search Chinese characters in Vim quickly?

Tags: vim, unicode, chinese-locale

I want to convert all string in Chinese to i18n, and want to search them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for simple, just search non-ascii characters

```
/[^\x00-\x7f]
```

according there may be many Chinese characters in the file, let's map a key in the `.vimrc` file

```
nnoremap <F10> /[^\x00-\x7f]<cr>
```

Now we can find Chinese character by `F10` key.